# It there a Python equivalent module of node-pty

Tags: python, pty

We have a site which exposes a remote shell terminal from an on-prem Node.js agent using `node-pty`. We also have a Python based agent, and would like to provive the experience.

The node.js code looks a bit like this:

```js
pty = require('node-pty');
ptyProcess = pty.spawn('bash', [], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    cols: 100,
    rows: 100,
    cwd: process.env.HOME,
    env: process.env
});

// Receiving terminal output
ptyProcess.on('data', function (data) {
    // send terminal data to web application
});

// Sending commands to terminal
_ptyProcess.write("ls -la");
```

I have looked a bit on Python pty but can't figure out the "on_data" event.

Thank you